# Can I get Voice to Text to spell my daughter's name correctly?

Tags: keyboard, voice-recognition, dictionary

Let's say my daughter's name is Danny.  But she/we spell it Dani.  Every time I use her name in VTT it is misspelled Danny and I have to correct it. PITA.  I've tried adding the name correctly spelled to the dictionary but that doesn't help.  She is in my contacts and if I say "text Dani" it works correctly. But on VTT no dice.

I have LG G4 running Android 6.0 version LS991ZVI using Gboard.  Yes I know it's an old phone but I love it and hate that the newer versions don't have the omnifunction button on the back.

Can someone please help?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I configure Google speech to text so that whenever I say "Frank" it writes "Franck"?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/243090/how-can-i-configure-google-speech-to-text-so-that-whenever-i-say-frank-it-writ)

Comment: No, @FranckDernoncourt, that did not work for me with VTT on a Pixel 4a 5g.

Comment: Interesting, you can't go to settings, dictionary & add Dani and make Danny the shortcut?

Comment: I did that.  But when I say "Danny"  I still get "Danny".

Comment: Yes this won't fix it.

Answer (score 0):

With Gboard, there's currently no option to correct the voice typing directly so that saying "Danny" writes "Dani".

The closest option is to add some entry in the Gboard personal dictionary to fix the already transcribed text (screenshots from Android 12 + Pixel 6 to fix "Frank" into "Franck", thanks [user1874594](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/92782/user1874594) for [showing me](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/243092/12202) this trick):

[image] [image]

Then you'll see the fixed word as a suggestion (only after the voice typing stopped being active):

[image]