# How can I configure Google speech to text so that whenever I say "Frank" it writes "Franck"?

Tags: voice-recognition, android-12, google-pixel-6

How can I configure Google speech to text so that whenever I say "Frank" it writes "Franck"?

I use Android 12 with a Google Pixel 6.

Comment: Glad to see you didn't have to change your name just to accommodate Google. ;)  Personally, I think you should spell it with two c's, but that's just my opinion.

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket I'm reading Frank so often that I might start to do the same typo at some point!

Comment: I think we need to arrange a posthumous meeting with Mary Shelley and get her to rename her creation to *Franckenstein*.  The confusion obviously is her fault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is isn't a direct way doing that. unfortunately Google voice to text translation is terribly biased. it offers various accents for English but it will not translate anything perfectly  and errors remain.

so how do you force corrections that come from bad voice to text translation  ?
from settings go to dictionary  &  add  Franck and make Frank the shortcut. I believe this is the closest you can come to what you you want to achieve[image]